# Java multi threads share a global map variable

Tags: java, multithreading

Now i have a requirement that handling 1 million data which in a global hashMap, obviously should use multi thread.Today i have tried two schames:

**1#**  Dividing the huge hashMap to a number of little hashMap and processing by a number of thread(one thread process one hashMap).It has a good performance.Obviously it doesn't need a synchronization between multi thread.

**2#**  I want use multi thread to process the same and huge hashMap.I will remove the item from hashmap which has been processed.I tried various method but failed.My key point is that ： I can get the real-time hashMap value when i generate a new thread but all thread can't notify each other what is the latest hashMap when all thread are running.**synchronized** can't solve my problem.

In **2#** how can i solve this problem.Thanks in advanced.

Here is part of my code:

```
class DoJob implements Runnable{
        private HugeDataHotelFormalMultiShare share = new HugeDataHotelFormalMultiShare();
        DoJob(HugeDataHotelFormalMultiShare share){
            this.share = share;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            testHotelMatchCommonShare(share.origMap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why synchronized can't solve your problem?

Comment: This looks like a job for ConcurrentHashmap.  @See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: I'm always worried when people who don't understand threading say "obviously should use multi thread".

Comment: @Kayaman indeed, beginners don't know that threading is the hardest topic in CS

Comment: @Kayaman i really didn't had much experience in multi thread. Yesterday i really really confused by this problem in my previous understanding in multi thread.Today i solved it.By the way my purpose come here is finding a best solution but not the worry.

Comment: @Sleiman Jneidi I found the problem.thanks.

Comment: @FloryLi That was my point. A lot of people don't understand multithreading, but they think it's some magical tool that makes everything go faster. Then they run into problems because they don't really understand what they're doing.

Comment: @Kayaman i have never think multi thread makes everything go faster.At least in this situation it indeed make my program go faster and save much time.If you have othter effective solution you can tell me but not saying like this.I don't think this is a good manner to answer others questions in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to step through the giant HashMap in a multi threaded manner you can use parallel streams (they are made exactly for this purpose):

```
HashMap<Object, Object> giantMap=new HashMap<>();
giantMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach((entry)->{
    Object key=entry.getKey();
    Object value=entry.getValue();
    //your logic with it
});
```

Side note: streams require Java8

Comment: My problems were solved and i will try your opinion.thanks.